# How can we do PGP encryption/decryption using RSA in Php?

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, pgp

I have installed GnuPG library and used below code for encryption and decryption:

```
$public_key = '/path/0xC6235F66-pub.asc';
$private_key = '/path/0xC6235F66-sec.asc';


function encryptText($public_key, $text)
{
    // Set GnuPG homedir to /tmp
    putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");

    $public_key = file_get_contents($public_key); 

    // Create new GnuPG instance
    $gpg = new gnupg();
    // Import given public key
    $key = $gpg->import($public_key);
    // Add imported key for encryption
    $gpg->addencryptkey($key['fingerprint']);
    // Encrypt the secret to a PGP message
    $enc = $gpg->encrypt($text);
    // Clear the encryption key
    $gpg->clearencryptkeys();
    // Return  the PGP message

    return $enc;
}


function decryptText($private_key, $encryptedText)
{
    // Set GnuPG homedir to /tmp
    putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");

    $private_key = file_get_contents($private_key); 

    // Create new GnuPG instance
    $gpg = new gnupg();
    // Import given public key
    $key = $gpg->import($private_key);
    // Add imported key for encryption
    $gpg->addencryptkey($key['fingerprint']);
    // Encrypt the secret to a PGP message
    $decText = $gpg->decrypt($encryptedText);
    // Clear the encryption key
    $gpg->clearencryptkeys();
    // Return  the PGP message

    return $decText;
}


$encrypted = encryptText($public_key, $input = 'just an example');
echo 'Encrypted text: '.$encrypted;

$decrypted = decryptText($private_key, $encrypted);
echo 'Decrypted text: '.$decrypted;

echo 'Match: ';
var_dump($input === $decrypted);
```

Using the above encryptText() function I got the encrypted text but unable to decrypt the same with function decryptText(). As i know, PGP encryption using rsa works with private & public key. I have both the keys in place and using public key for encryption which is giving some encrypted string output but unable to decrypt the encrypted string.

Please help here.

Comment: what key are you using to attempt the decryption?

Comment: I am using public key for encryption and private key for decryption along with its fingerprint. I have edited my post with fresh code, please review.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hard-code the fingerprint. You should also use the private key to decrypt.

```php
function encryptText($public_key, $data)
{
    $gpg = gnupg_init();
    ['fingerprint' => $fingerprint] = gnupg_import($gpg, $public_key);
    gnupg_addencryptkey($gpg, $fingerprint);

    return base64_encode(gnupg_encrypt($gpg, $data));
}

function decryptText($private_key, $data)
{
    $gpg = gnupg_init();
    ['fingerprint' => $fingerprint] = gnupg_import($gpg, $private_key);
    gnupg_addencryptkey($gpg, $fingerprint);

    return gnupg_decrypt($gpg, base64_decode($data));
}

print $encrypted = encryptText($public_key, $input = 'just an example');
print $decrypted = decryptText($private_key, $encrypted);
var_dump($input === $decrypted);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. No fingerprint was generating thus it was returning blank string for encrypted, decrypted.
Though the same i tried in object based gpg, it is returning the encrypted text but it is not decrypting using the private key.
Still stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This follow code working for me:

```
    putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");
    $gpg = new gnupg();
    $gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);
    $publicData = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/web/resources/keys/public.asc');
    $privateData = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/web/resources/keys/SECRET.asc');
    $publicKey = $gpg->import($publicData);
    $privateKey = $gpg->import($privateData);
    $gpg->addencryptkey($publicKey['fingerprint']);
    $gpg->adddecryptkey($privateKey['fingerprint'],"YOUR_PASSPHASE");
    $encrypt = ($gpg->encrypt('Data to encrypt'));
    echo $encrypt;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($gpg->decrypt($encrypt));
    echo '</pre>';die;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted some time ago, so a new answer may not be useful any longer, but the biggest issue with the current version of your code (as posted in the question on the day I write this answer) is that you're adding your decryption key (private) as an *encryption* key (public) by accident. In `decryptText()`, you'll need to change `addencryptkey()` to `adddecryptkey()`, and `clearencryptkeys()` to `cleardecryptkeys()`.

You may also need a passphrase for the decryption key (private). That depends on whether the key is set up to require one, though.